# Interpolating Merra reanalysis

Tags: atmosphere, atmosphere-modelling, climate-models

Merra re-analysis ara available for  a coarser horizontal grid with resolution of 0.625 × 0.5 degrees providing differents parameters : Precipitation, Temperature ....This been said, I want to interpolate continuously theses parameters ( More precisely : For each coordinate I want to know elevation, Precipitation , and other parameters ( Look the following example ).

**Time step  // Latitude // Longitude // Elevation // Precipitation  ...**

1    ................ 30    .............     -7     ..................   1500 ...................       x             x    x ....x

1       ...............          30.25   .........     -7   ...................     x x ..........................x

1  .................             31.11  .....      -6.63    ...................xx.......................X

If you have an idea how to interpolate these data I would be grateful.

Comment: Many people use GCMs inappropriately, in water resources analysis, which is not what GCMs are designed for. They struggle with poor accuracy, poor precision and resolution, so it is good to see Mohamed looking into the problem. Could you expand the question so that we can see where you are going with this? In down-scaling from this grid size I suggest that you pay particular attention to the variation in relief for each grid cell, and the fraction of the cell that is open water.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recoment using [interp2 funtion](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html) from Matlab or any other equivalent in other languages. I have used it to do similar tasks.